# Swing plug-in for Eclipse Juno 4.2?

Tags: java, swing

What open-source eclipse plugin do I install to program with/in Java Swing?

I have Eclipse Juno (4.2?) installed and everything is running good so far.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - personally I'm not using any plugin specifically for swing.

Comment: The question is: What open-source eclipse plugin do I install to program with/in Java Swing?  Looks like WindowBuilder is not available for Eclipse Juno yet.. just my luck for installing the latest Eclipse IDE I guess...

Comment: Oh, can't help you with that then, I prefer not using a code generating tool for my layouts.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Thanks anyway, I hope to be able to just code it too.. will see how it goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swing donot require any plugin to run, Swing library is an official Java GUI toolkit released by Sun Microsystems. It is used to create Graphical user interfaces with Java.

You can follow this **[LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html)** to setup and run you first program, based on Swing..

And for more details, GOOGLE IT! It will provide you more than enough information that you need.

Hope this helps out. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you soooo much. Been googling but sometimes nothing comes up that makes sense when your new to something. Your link is Puuurrrfect :)